# Java - DatagramSocket only receives packet after network reset

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, datagram

I'm facing a very annoying problem problem here trying to receive a 5 bytes UDP packet with my Java application.

First of all, here's my code:

```
DatagramSocket socketD = new DatagramSocket(7502);

byte[] bufRec = new byte[5];
DatagramPacket RXpacket = new DatagramPacket(bufRec, bufRec.length);

socketD.receive(RXpacket);
```

This is the receive part, the sending part is working fine.

My problem is that this code only works if I connect to the network after the DatagramSocket.reiceve method, otherwise the code will be stuck in this method "waiting for the packet" forever (Or til timeout expires). Other "workaround" I found is call the receive method, then disconnect and reconnect the network. It works too, doing this one time the application start receiving the packets.

I have serious suspicions the problem is with the Java application, because dumping my network with Wireshark I can see the packets arriving, but the receive method still stuck.

Other test I've done is sending these packets as broadcast in my network, but the problem remains (doing the changes in the receive code too).

Anyone, please, have any idea what is happening here?

Thanks in advance,
Rodrigo Wantuk.

Comment: The method blocks, so if it does not receive any incoming messages, the call here will block until it does. When you run the above code in a infinite loop (printing out to sysout or something the results received), and you send messages, only the first packet is received?

What size packets do you send?

Comment: @JorisHilhorst I'm sending 5 bytes packet. My intent is save the information received in a file, but now, for tests only, I'm incrementing a counter. I dind't reiceve any packet till reseting my connection, but when I do this, the packets come.

Comment: Ok but do you run the sending in a separate program or as part of the same program? to test the client server stuff you would need 1 sender and 1 receiver program (or thread, ofcourse), as the receiver will block until it gets new input, which means your code would never reach the place where you would send. That's why I am curious about your sending code.